# Reason for leaving? Hibernation method?

Tags: magic

All right, in a medieval fantasy world a tyrant conquers a peaceful kingdom and the native docile dragons immediately migrate to a new geographical location and begin to hibernate until said tyrant dies or is killed.

Firstly, I would like to know why you think the dragons would leave.

Secondly, I would need a detailed explanation as to how the dragons hibernate, preferably the hibernation would be of magical origin.

Comment: Please limit yourself to one question per post.

Comment: We are not here to write your story so the first question is too broad. The second question is about something magical and you would need to define the magic in your world, which mean you would have to be the one who defines the details.

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding! Sadly this sounds like you [High Concept](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4868/how-to-deal-with-i-have-a-high-concept-please-do-my-work-for-me-questions) and are expecting us to do your work. We need one concrete question where we can objectively rate answers against each other, not a task to start brainstorming... We are here to help people after all, it's not the job of the community to think of ways for you to write your story. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more.

Comment: I probably shouldn't have done an answer for this because its idea generation but im not deleting it now. though both ideas are classics.

Comment: I'm kinda troubleshooting this site right now, believe me my world is completely fleshed out and I have set up my magic system. I just wanted to see the communities response to a question like this, thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 2):

The only reason I can see them leaving is because most humans are a massive pain, disturbing them and they can't be bothered to deal with that. Also maybe another reason in idea 2.

As for the hibernation extending life. There are two options I will sugest;

1. Most being of that amount of power are immortal in body, the thing that limits them is the capacity of their soul, which is gradually expended by making memories. So by going into sleep and not making new memories, they extend their life.
2. Magical energy  passively can extend the life of cells in the body, causing the beings life to extend. As dragons are born with strong magic they have this benefit from when they are born. However even using abit of magic power actively (even for enforcing your body) will cause damage that will decrease your life span. So dragons learn to suppress thier energy, in order to live longer, the pinacle of this causes hibernation.
   This can also explain why dragons don't often participate in conflict, why human mages life span is so much smaller than a dragon and why beings with little intelligent or instinct and lacking control over magic while still using it (like goblins), have mages with the shortest lifespan.

Comment: I'm honestly surprised you took this question seriously, it was more of a trial and error question to see how people responded, but I do like your answers, they make sense, although I can't help but ask if you got some of the thinking behind your answers from the Eragon books?

Comment: @TheMaelstromSoul Nope, I dont think so. I did read the eragon books when I was younger but they didn't leave a big impression on me and the one time I tried to read it again I didn't like it as much.

Comment: It just seemed like it was related to the lore of how dragons have eldunari in Dragon, bur obviously not.